# How do I deal with case insensitivity in sweet_xml?

Tags: xml, xpath, elixir

I'm using `sweet_xml` to parse some XML that may look like this:

```
<ASX VERSION="3.0">
  <ENTRY CLIENTSKIP="NO">
    <TITLE>Item 1</TITLE>
    <REF HREF="http://kexp-mp3-2.cac.washington.edu:8000/" />
  </ENTRY>
</ASX>
```

I want a list of maps that have a `title` and `file` attributes, the latter of which is the `href` of the `REF` node. I can do this with:

```
SweetXml.xpath(file, ~x"//ENTRY"l, name: ~x"./TITLE/text()", file: ~x"./REF/@HREF")
```

However, I want to handle any type of casing in the node name. For example, `<Ref href... />` or `<title>` should work.

I want to do this without changing the value of the nodes, so I can't just `String.downcase` the whole thing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, XML is case sensitive _by definition_, and case-insensitivity would be so far out of spec that it is unlikely any existing library would support it.  Since sweet_xml source is on GitHub, your best option is probably to download a local copy and modify it to be case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Jim Garrison in comments, `XML` itself is *case-sensitive*, that’s why there unlikely is a solution provided by any library out of the box. The good news is that you want to preserve *casing* for *the values of nodes*. That is easy: everything inside `<>` might be downcased:

```
Regex.replace(~r|\<.*?\>|, input, fn x -> String.downcase(x) end)
```

The above produces (irrelevant parts omitted):

```
#⇒                         ⇓ HERE
#⇒ "<asx version=...<title>Item 1</title>...</asx>"
```